# Combine columns into strings ignoring None

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is the dataframe that i have:

```py
list = [['man walks', 'slowly', 'back'], ['slowly','None', 'None'], ['sunny','sons','None']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list)
```

which results in this dataframe

```py
    0             1      2
0   man walks   slowly  back
1   slowly      None    None
2   sunny       sons    None
```

How do I add the contents of each row together ONLY IF the value is not equal to `None`?
Desired Result is another column that looks like this:

```py
    Sum
0  man walks slowly back 
1  slowly
2  sunny sons
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those `None` are actually strings in your example. Assuming they are indeed `None`, you can use [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) (which removes missing values by default), [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate with `join`:

```
df1.stack().groupby(level=0).agg(' '.join)

0    man walks slowly back
1                   slowly
2               sunny sons
dtype: object
```